# Registration allows duplicate user name in Access

Tags: c#

I do have a problem in **checking username** and **password** in my registration form. When I tend to register the same username and password that's is already in my database(Access), still it allows to register. I just wanna trap it however, I don't know how to that.

What I want to output is that, I want a trap that says "Account Exists, Try Again!" or "Username Exists!"

```
   using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.ComponentModel; using System.Data; using System.Drawing; using  System.Linq; using System.Text; using System.Windows.Forms; using    System.Data.OleDb; using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
   namespace Login {    public partial class Register : Form    {
   private OleDbConnection personalConn;
   private OleDbCommand oleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand();
   private String connParam = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Majel\Tic Tac    Toe\Database\data.accdb";

   public Register()
   {
       personalConn = new OleDbConnection(connParam);
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           personalConn.Open();
           oleDbCmd.Connection = personalConn;

           if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "")
           {
               int temp;
               oleDbCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO data(Users,Pass) Values('" + this.textBox1.Text.ToString() + "','" +   this.textBox2.Text + "');";

               temp = oleDbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

               if (temp > 0)
               {
                   textBox1.Text = null;
                   textBox2.Text = null;
                   MessageBox.Show("Registration Success!");
                   this.Hide();

                   Form1 frm = new Form1();
                   frm.Show(); 
               } 
               personalConn.Close();
           }                  
       }  
       catch (Exception)
       {   
           MessageBox.Show("Invalid!, Duplicate Data.");  
       }  
   }
```

> Notes: textBox1= username
>            textBox2= password  Your attention is much highly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Your code requires improvements. Beware of `SQL Injection attacks`, use parameterized query. Also you are inserting username every time. To check if user already exists, you need to query using `SELECT` command.

Comment: Sorry, but I find it complicated. I'm still a student.

Comment: not even a comment about what I wrote ok, good luck with the implementation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code which uses oledbcommand parameters using `?` placeholder as mentioned in [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx). Also I have added `using` block which should Close opened connection implicitly.

```
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connParam))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select count(*) from data where Users = ?"))
{
     con.Open();    
     cmd.Connection = con;              
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", textBox1.Text);        
     object objRes = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

     if (objRes == null || (int)objRes == 0)
     {
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO data (Users,Pass) values(?, ?);";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Users", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", textBox2.Text);
        int iRes = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if(iRes > 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Registration Success!");
     }
     else
       errorProvider2.SetError(textBox1, "This username has been using by another user.");
}
```

Comment: sir how about the con.Close()? where do I put it?

Comment: Sir, how to create .udl?

Comment: `con.Close()` is not required when we use `using` block. Make a `test.udl` if your connection is not working. Open notepad and save as `"test.udl"` it would create one.

Comment: '   if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null)' Sir, there's an error "ExcecuteScalar: Connection property has not been initialize"

Comment: I have added this line `cmd.Connection = con;`

Comment: Sir, where should I use the **test.udl**?, is it a replace connection for my current connection string?

Comment: Where should I put this **cmd.Connection = con;** sir?

Comment: sir, still doesn't work. It still refers to **if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null)**,  "ExcecuteScalar: Connection property has not been initialize"

Comment: sir,it worked however when I tend to register new account that is not in the database, it says ** "This username has been using by another user."** what shall I do sir?

Comment: Forget about `test.udl` it was something to check connection. It was not supposed to be added in the code. About `Connection Property ...` error check the updated answer. It should be working according to your requirement.

Comment: Sir, how to save a file into your own account?, sir please help me. I created another discussion sir. Here's the link, I know you can help me.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038339/how-to-save-value-to-your-own-accountc-access/26039027#26039027]

Comment: Sir, the code that I used for the other question is basically coming from here. I just want to know  if when you have the account then how to save texts for your own account?

Answer (score 0):

You almost *never* use data (in this case, a username) as the **primary key** for a record in a database. Chance are, your access database is set up the same way.

This means that there is nothing at the DBMS layer that will stop this from occurring, short of making the username the primary key (not recommended).

The solution is to perform a SELECT query to get the count of records with that username, and only allow the insert if the count is 0. You *might* be able to write a trigger to do this for you, and make the DBMS "reject" the insert, but given your (apparent) level with databases, I wouldn't try that at this point.

To get the count:

> SELECT Count(*) FROM Users WHERE userName=@userName

A paramaterized query here is **crucial** to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: Sir, Can you provide codes on how to do that?, please sir I really need it. Please do help me.

Comment: @user3349418 I provided a sample query. I'll try to help from there, but I am not going to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Drawing; 
using  System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Windows.Forms; 
using    System.Data.OleDb; 
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace Login 
{    

   public partial class Register : Form    
   {




   public Register()
   {

       InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           if(text1Box1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "")
           {
                MessageBox.Show("Mandatory fields password or user is empty");
                retrun; //I'm not sure if this return is need. Remove it if MessageBox "breaks" the execution of the code below.
           }
           OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"Select * from Data where User=@User");
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", textBox1.Text);


           DataSet dst = SqlManager.GetDataSet(cmd, "Data");

           if(dst.Tables[0].Rows > 0)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("User already exist");
               return; //again i'm not sure that this return is needed.
           }

           Insert("Data", "User", textBox1.Text, "Pass", textBox2.Text);         

           textBox1.Text = null;
           textBox2.Text = null;
           MessageBox.Show("Registration Success!");
           this.Hide();

           Form1 frm = new Form1();
           frm.Show();

       }  
       catch (Exception ex)
       {   
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);  
       }
   }
```

You need 1 class make it SqlManager.

```
  public class SqlManager
  {
      private String connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Majel\Tic Tac    Toe\Database\data.accdb";


      public static GetOleDbConnection(OleDbCommand cmd)
      {
          if(cmd.Connection == null)
          {
               OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
               conn.Open();
               cmd.Connection = conn;
               return conn;
          }

          return cmd.Connection;
      }

      public static int ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand cmd)
      {
           OleDbConnection conn = GetSqlConnection(cmd);

           try
           {
              return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           }
           catch
           {
              throw;
           }
           finally
           {
              conn.Close();
           }

      }
    public static DataSet GetDataSet(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        return GetDataSet(cmd, "Table");
    }

    public static DataSet GetDataSet(SqlCommand cmd, string defaultTable)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = GetSqlConnection(cmd);

        try
        {
            DataSet resultDst = new DataSet();

            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                adapter.Fill(resultDst, defaultTable);
            }

            return resultDst;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }


  }
```

Here is another method you can put in the form class:

```
  public virtual void Insert(string TableName, params object[] colValues)
    {
        if (colValues == null || colValues.Length % 2 != 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid column values passed in. Expects pairs (ColumnName, ColumnValue).");

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO " + TableName + " ( {0} ) VALUES ( {1} )");

        string insertCols = string.Empty;
        string insertParams = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < colValues.Length; i += 2)
        {
            string separator = ", ";
            if (i == colValues.Length - 2)
                separator = "";

            string param = "@P" + i;

            insertCols += colValues[i] + separator;
            insertParams += param + separator;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(param, colValues[i + 1]);
        }

        cmd.CommandText = string.Format(cmd.CommandText, insertCols, insertParams);

        DA.SqlManager.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
    }
```

Like other guys tell you use parameters in this case you will avoid sql injection. Read in wikipedia about it. Also I add some structure for your program, it is not perfect but I should write a lot for more. It is possible to have some typos here, because I wrote the code here. How you make the check, you fetch the data from database for the user which you write in textbox1.Text. If the dataSet have rows that means at the moment there is existing user with this name. If you don't know what is data set read System.Data.

You should learn to write data access in other classes !

Answer (score 0):

Try this with your Existing Code :

```
oleDbCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO data(Users,Pass) Values('" + this.textBox1.Text.ToString() + "','" +   this.textBox2.Text + "') SELECT '" + this.textBox1.Text.ToString() + "','" +   this.textBox2.Text + "' WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT Users,Pass FROM data WHERE Users='" + this.textBox1.Text.ToString() +"');";

temp = oleDbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (temp > 0)
           {
               textBox1.Text = null;
               textBox2.Text = null;
               MessageBox.Show("Registration Success!");
               this.Hide();

               Form1 frm = new Form1();
               frm.Show(); 
           } 
else
          {
            MessageBox.Show("Username is already Present !!!");
          }
```

It returns `0` if the username is already present in data.